# Select last two rows from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database like this:

```
+----------+----------+------+
| username | password | time |
+----------+----------+------+
| a        | b        | 1234 |
| c        | d        | 5678 |
| e        | f        | 9012 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Now I have to arrange this by time so I ran:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `time`")
```

This showed me rows arranged by time in ascending order, but I have to get only username `c` and `e` or I have to get the last two rows from the query.

I have tried:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `time` LIMIT 2')
```

But this showed me usernames `a` and `c` but I have to get the last two, how to do that?

Comment: order by time DESC limit 2

Comment: This all went crazily fast...

Comment: What is the primary key of the table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: The OP question is about Mysql...not SQL SVR

Comment: Be careful! MySQL doesn't have the TOP keyword. Don't worry though, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22176084/edit) your answer.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2
```

Adding the `DESC` keyword will sort the results in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I will win next time ;p

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2')
```

Comment: The mysql_ has been deprecated and removed in php 7.1, you should use mysqli_ instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an id field with AUTO_INCREMENT set.

To get the last two from the table.

```
       SELECT * FROM table
       ORDER BY time DESC
       LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Not only does your answer offer no additional information, it's actually wrong. His table doesn't have an `id` column. Also the question pretty much implies he wants the latest 2 with regards to the time column.

Comment: I assumed the table has an id. he didn't mentioned that.

Comment: He included an example ordered by time. And you could have asked for clarification in a comment, which is usually a better idea than assuming.

Comment: what is the primary key for that table then.  A table with out primary key hast no identifiable tupple

Comment: He can create a table without a primary key. While he might run into problems then, depending on how data gets into that table, it possibly doesn't really matter and he can assume the time to behave similar to an ID. I agree that he should have a primary key, but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, if he has a primary key, it would be easier determining a row in the table and the question was about that.  And that is the problem he is now confronting.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He does say he wants to "arrange this by time" and then pick the "last two rows from the query". This boils down to "the latest 2 entries in the database with respect to the time column". While it would probably help with other problems he might encounter, a primary key is not necessaray to solve this particular problem. That's all I'm saying.